# Checking if multiple fields contains a String

Tags: spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using MongoTemplate to construct a query which searches for a String (exactly like `LIKE %abc%` in SQL) across multiple fields. So, I have an object like:

```
{
  "location": "Pacific",
  "status": "Closed",
  "badge": "220394"
}
```

**WHAT I TRIED**:

Now, I wrote a query like:

```
Criteria freeTextCriteria = Criteria.where("badge").regex(".*" + freeText + ".*", "i");
dynamicQuery.addCriteria(freeTextCriteria);
```

This return above object only when I pass `freeText` as `2039` but not returning any results when I pass `freeText` as `220394` (full value). Why is this happening?

Also, I need to make this query for multiple fields. So, `2039` should match against `location` OR `status` OR `badge`. When I run the below query:

```
Criteria freeTextCriteria = 
    Criteria.where("location").regex(".*" + freeText + ".*", "i")
        .orOperator(Criteria.where("badge").regex(".*" + freeText + ".*", "i"));
dynamicQuery.addCriteria(freeTextCriteria);
```

Above doesn't return any results even with partial texts. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Criteria freeTextCriteria = new Criteria();
freeTextCriteria.orOperator(Criteria.where("location").regex(".*"+ freeText +".*"), Criteria.where("badge").regex(".*"+ freeText +".*"));
Query dynamicQuery = new Query(freeTextCriteria);
mongoTemplate.find(dynamicQuery, <Yourclass>.class, "collectionName");
```

This will work.